# Gatling> Json response map with Json File

Tags: scala, gatling

Hi I want to validate my Json File saved in resources with the Json response via Get method.
My Saved Json File looks like this, which is in an array
[{
"id":"123"
}]

I am unable to map the File with Response.

```
object Products {

val jsonFetchProductIDs = ElFileBody("abc.json")
val fetchProductIds: HttpRequestBuilder = http("fetch")
.get("endpoint")
.body(jsonFetch)

val products = http("Products")
.get("endpoint")

}

class ProductsTest extends Simulation {

val productIdInfo = exec(
  Products.products
  .check(status.is(200), jsonPath("$.id").ofType[Map[String,Any]].findAll.saveAs("productsID"))
)

val productIdResult = exec(session => {

val id = session.get("id").asOption[String]
  foreach("${productsID}", "id") {
    exec(session => {
      val idMap = session("id").as[Map[String, Any]]
      val allId = idMap(" allId")
      session.set("allId", allId)
    })
  }
session
  })

  val getproductidscenario1 = scenario("Products ID")

.exec(Login.login)
.exec(EventBus.openSSE)
.exec(Accounts.fetchInitialAccounts)
.pause(10)
.exec(productIdInfo)
.exec(productIdResult)

  setUp (

getproductidscenario1.inject(atOnceUsers(1)).protocols(HttpConf.httpConf)
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the command below to compare the result against file content

> bodyString.is(ElFileBody("expected_response.json"))